# What parameters can I pass in the tkraise() function?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am curious as to what parameters I can pass into `tkraise()` but I can't find any reference to it in the official documentation as seen in pic provided.

[image: no results]

Just some code to show you what I mean:

```
#Define Frames
loginFrame=tk.Frame(root)
registerFrame=tk.Frame(root)
frameList=[loginFrame,registerFrame]
#Configure all Frames
for frame in frameList:
    frame.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky='news')
    frame.configure(bg='white')
#Frame Raise Function
def raiseframe(frame):
    frame.tkraise()
```

Perhaps their are some transition effects etc? Just curious.

Comment: It's a `tkinter.Frame` widget method. Here's some [documentation](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.tkraise-method), such as it is. It has one optional argument which can be another frame to place the calling frame above. The default is to lift the frame to the logical top of the stacking order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **tkraise()**
>
> Raise this widget in the stacking order.
>
> Used to stack the frames on top of each other
>
> syntax:
>
> `tkraise(aboveThis=None)`